# Cómo disparo una función con google forms?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Estoy tratando de crear por medio de google sheet, abrir un form y por medio de la acción submit crear una serie de pasos donde me cree una carpeta en el drive de google. Ya tengo prácticamente todo el script pero me falta el paso mas importante, donde al momento de dar submit a mi form este llame la función de creación de carpeta, pero no logro hacerlo, ya tengo el código pero no me funciona.

```
function triggerForm(){ 
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('createCarpetaPath')
  .forForm('idForm')
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}

function createCarpetaPath(){
  var currentSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ruta");
  var newFolderID = parentFolder.createFolder(currentSheetName + "1").getId();

  Logger.log(newFolderID);
  saveAsSpreadsheet(newFolderID);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("El formulario ha sido enviado exitosamente");
}
```

Al momento de abrir el form y enviarlo, lo único que me aparece que se registro mi respuesta, ni la alerta me aparece. No sé qué pueda ser ya que por más que veo no encuentro un error o algo que me falte. También probé con esta sentencia:

```
forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onFormSubmit().create()
```

Pero tampoco me funciona.
Espero me puedan ayudar con este problema, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Podría ser que el que no encuentres un error se deba a un bug de Google Apps Script que en ciertos casos no se registran los errores cuando se usa el proyecto predeterminado de Google Cloud Platform y el runtime V8.

Para ver los errores podrías intentar cambiar el runtime para usar el antiguo (Rhino) o bien crear un proyecto de Google Cloud Platform estándar.

Por otro lado, los activadores cuenta con el envío del mensaje de error por correo electrónico de forma predeterminada, sólo que el envío es sólo una vez al día, pero es posible cambiar la frecuencia a inmediatamente. Este ajuste no se puede hacer mediante código, sólo mediante la interface web, para esto

1. Abre el proyecto de Apps Script
2. Ve a la página de activadores del proyecto
3. Edita el activador
4. Modifica la configuración de la notificación y guarda.

En cuanto a tu código, este tiene un problema, no es posible llamar `getUi()` desde un activador "on form submit", así que debes quitar la línea

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("El formulario ha sido enviado exitosamente");
```

Quitando esa línea ya debería funcionar tu script.